Is there a way to expose a computer's local folder to Android via adb?
I want an Android app to process files in a large directory with many files. I would usually just transfer the files to the device via adb push. But this time around, the folder is much larger than the phone's storage capacity.
Is there a way for me to expose a local computer's files (Linux or macOS) to the phone to be accessed by the app?

Android device USB transfer speed would be a limitation, followed by battery life, see: USB Host mode, and you would have to make your PC the equivalent of a USB drive, up to which capacity an OTG capable phone could support external usb storage?

adb won't help you in this case as adb is designed to be used form PC side only. And reversing the connection isn't intended, thus not supported by plain Android. Normally people are using SMB/CIFS, FTP, SCP or HTTP shares on the PC and e.g. a matching file explorer that can access one of those shares.

I see. Thank you for the insights @MorrisonChang and Robert.
